# I am trying to use the MYSQL "IF NOT EXISTS" syntax to only create Views that are missing on the new box

Tags: mysql, view

I am tasked with checking a MYSQL 5.5 database that has a 100+ Views that have been migrated over from a different box. Some Views are missing. I am trying to use the MYSQL "IF NOT EXISTS" syntax to only create Views that are missing on the new box. I do not want to waste DB resources by using "CREATE or REPLACE" syntax to recreate ALL VIEWS. I could use help, if this is possible.  I've tried the following approaches without success:

```
CREATE VIEW (if not exists `view_full_name_ee`) as 
select `e`.`id` AS `id`,concat(`e`.`name_first`,_latin1' ',`e`.`name_last`) AS `full_name`,
concat(`e`.`name_last`,_latin1', ',`e`.`name_first`) AS `full_name_lf`,
`e`.`title` AS `title`,`e`.`login` AS `login`,`e`.`credentials` AS `credentials` 
from `ee` `e`;

If not Exists (select 1 from `view_full_name_ee`) then
CREATE VIEW `view_full_name_ee` as 
select `e`.`id` AS `id`,concat(`e`.`name_first`,_latin1' ',`e`.`name_last`) AS `full_name`,
concat(`e`.`name_last`,_latin1', ',`e`.`name_first`) AS `full_name_lf`,
`e`.`title` AS `title`,`e`.`login` AS `login`,`e`.`credentials` AS `credentials` 
from `ee` `e`;
```

Comment: Don't you only have to run this once anyway?

Comment: 100+ views? that's nothing. do create/replace and get on with more important things, like coffee.

Comment: Apologies for the SQLServer answer.  There's not a way to do this in MySQL.  100 views will not inconvenience the server by much at all, so create or replace (like Marc said) is probably the best option.